# Why is Alternating Least Squares "best used in systems that are centered around implicit data"?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, svd

I am going through the paper [Netflix prize and SVD](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2014spring/420projects/math420-UPS-spring-2014-gower-netflix-SVD.pdf) by Stephen Gower in order to understand the solutions to the Netflix prize. In the section "Learning algorithms" it is stated : "ALS is best used in systems that are centered around implicit data" as opposed to explicit feedback ratings of users on items. I could not find further discussion of this in the paper.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Explicit data is made up of a users rating of a movie. 
Implicit data takes into account the users behavior; how long they watched the movie, how many times, search history..
Therefore, the implicit dataset is much larger and can represent all users whereas explicit only represents users who frequently rate movies. For explicit data, there are a lot of missing values, so the model's goal is to fill in all the users missing rating values based only on the users other ratings. Implicit models, on the other hand, determine the likelihood of a user liking a particular movie based on many factors about the user, factors about the movie, and how those relate. ALS is both capable of forming models for implicit and explicit datasets, but implicit datasets are better representations of users, so implicit models are aswell.

Mathematically, an explicit model could be created with a single equation whereas an implicit model would use a system of equations to form a model.

http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf
The above article mentions explicit vs. implicit some.